# Combining Classes and Event Listeners: `this` keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, functional-programming, jquery-events

I'm having a hard time answering my question, and I think it's simply because "class" and "this" and other such terms are too generic for effective Googling.

---

Consider the following code:

```
function product (name) {
    var _productName;

    this.getProductName = function() {
        return this._productName;
    };

    this.alertProductName = function() {
        // This errors because `this` is a reference to the HTML <input> tag and not the class
        alert(this.getProductName());
    }

    this._productName = name;

    var $productButton = $('<input type="button" value="What is my name?" />');
        $productButton.on('click', this.alertProductName);

    $('body').append($productButton);
}

var widget = new product('Widget');

widget.alertProductName();
```

jQuery (or maybe Javascript itself) is resetting what the *this* keyword points to once product::alertProductName is called as a callback to an event. I can't find any other way to access a specific *instance* of this class from within a function used as a callback. It looks like Javascript used to have arguments.callee but that has been deprecated.

Does anyone know how I can access a specific instance of a class in this manner? If not, is there a better way to write this so that I don't have this problem to begin with?

Comment: Typical answer: cache `this` in the higher scope, like `var self = this` then use `self` in place of `this`.

Comment: or use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Comment: Stay away from variables like `$productButton` so you can use JavaScript with PHP, just use `var productButton`. `$('body')`, `$.ajax()` and the like are fine. It will save potential future headaches. Just a comment.

Comment: @PHPglue: It's a convention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign. I see no confusion.

Comment: No, I create JavaScript with PHP sometimes, so your variable within double quotes in PHP would be undefined PHP. That was just advice.

Comment: @PHPglue: Using jQuery $ syntax inside a PHP double-quoted string sounds like a really bad practice on it's own. I try to use 'string '. $var .' string' in PHP instead of "{$var}" anyway. Either way, I don't combine PHP and JS in ways that this is an issue.

Comment: For more info about constructor functions, prototype and the value of `this` maybe the following answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 (it looks like you're not using prototype at all at the moment)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the method `alertProductName` is invoked by an event handler, by default `this` inside the event handler method refers to the dom element that triggered the event.

Since you are using an constructor my preferred solution will be is to pass a custom execution context to the `alertProductName` method using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) - [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) doe the same but no [IE < 9 support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility)

```
function product(name) {
    var _productName;

    this.getProductName = function () {
        return this._productName;
    };

    this.alertProductName = function () {
        // This errors because `this` is a reference to the HTML <input> tag and not the class
        alert(this.getProductName());
    }

    this._productName = name;

    var $productButton = $('<input type="button" value="What is my name?" />');
    $productButton.on('click', $.proxy(this.alertProductName, this));//here use $.proxy()

    $('body').append($productButton);
}

var widget = new product('Widget');

widget.alertProductName();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zMH3w/)

Another solution is to use a closure variable to refer to the widget element, ex: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s2ms5/) - this will not work if you are planning to make sure of prototype functions for the constructor

Comment: I didn't know about $.proxy() and it seems to exist specifically to combat this issue. `this` will continue to point to my class, while I must use event.target to regain access to the DOM element that was clicked.

elclanrs' method of caching `this` in another variable called self works too. I can use self.getProductName() correctly and continue using `this` to access the DOM element.

Is there anything you can tell me about using one over the other?

Comment: @TylerV. [e.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) or [e.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) depending on your need

Comment: @TylerV. read the last part of the answer... other than that it is fine

Comment: @TylerV. look at this example using prototype functions http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zMH3w/2/

Comment: I understand now. This has been very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you think it is.

This answers it nicely
[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)