# Difference between '$add' and 'var add' in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables

What's the difference between:

```
var add = "Hello";
```

and

```
$add = "Hello";
```

Could you tell me the difference between the two solutions without saying that one of them does not require jQuery ?

Thanks.

Comment: neither one requires jquery. The one with the `$variable` is just a naming convention some use to indicate it's might be a jquery object. I say might because really a variable can contain anything in javascript and can change. There is no special context to `$` in javascript. Even in jquery `$` is just a variable that could be redefined at a latter date if you chose to.

Comment: Neither has anything to do with jQuery. `$add` is just another name. The difference is that the version with `var` is local to the current scope (function, etc.), while the other will be global.

Comment: Note that you have 2 questions implied here. Both have already been answered, just separately (See Joseph's and Paul's comments.)

Answer (score 1):

The first creates a scoped variable--one that's only available inside its parent function.

The second creates a global variable and is not a jQuery object, despite the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

Naming a variable with a dollar sign is pure JavaScript and doesn't require JQuery. This may be a naming convention (see [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)). Omitting 'var' makes the variable global and changes the scope of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The var keyword in front of a variable will basically declare that variable within the current scope. But, if that var keyword is missing, Javascript will search up the scope chain to see if there is a variable with that name in a different scope. And, since it finds a variable with the same name – testVar – in the global scope, Javascript will use that variable instead of declaring a new one local to the function.

$var is the name of the variable nothing more, so the proper way would be
var $var;