# JQuery variable prefixed with $

Tags: jquery

```
var $parent = $('<p>').addClass('exanple-class').prop('id','id-parent').appendTo('body');
```

I partially understand the statement above, but why declare the variable prefixed with dollar sign ? Why not use `var parent = somecode`, I've searched and cant find a definition

Comment: It's just a naming convention to show that the variable contains a jQuery object. The $ provides no other value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat of a convention. It lets you know, without having to go back to check where the variable was declared, that it contains a `jQuery` object.