# How can change maxFiles in dropzone dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone

I have a select option element in my project with two options, books and images. For book option, I want to allow only single file to upload. But for images option I need to allow multiple file selection. I am trying to this way but not succeeded:

```
 Dropzone.options.frmMediaDropzone = {
   maxFilesize: 99,
   acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.pdf",
   parallelUploads: 1,
   addRemoveLinks: true,
   maxFiles: 100,
   init: function() {
     myDropzone = this;
     this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
       console.log(file);
     });

     this.on("success", function(file, response) {
       console.log(response.imageName);
     });
   }
 };
```

On option change, I am trying this:

```
Dropzone.options.frmMediaDropzone.maxFiles = 1;
```

But its not working. If anyone has idea please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a two ways of doing this. You can either dynamically create your dropzone and then change the attributes of it using .attr, or create a listener event in your init property when you define the dropzone.

See this link for a similar example (See the 2nd answer):
[Dropzone: change acceptedFiles dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510204/dropzone-change-acceptedfiles-dynamically/43040586)

Comment: Thanx Ryan, I think this would be helpful. But I have two dropzonez on same page and both having the same class. Is it possible to assign name to the inputs to get particular input?

Comment: Rather than using a class selector, use an id selector. $('#myid') rather than $('.myclass').

Comment: Yes but this is I am asking that how can set id to hidden inputs because hidden inputs are generated by dropzone. below are these two hidden inputs without id or name:
<input type="file" class="dz-hidden-input" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="dz-hidden-input" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.pdf" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your meaning. In your html, you will have a form for your dropzone, so you can use that id. If you dynamically create a dropzone, you can assign it to a variable and then use that variable.

Comment: Yes Ryan, my form has an id but the dropzone generates hidden input file elements outside the form so form id can't help. But anyway on your suggestion I get the same thing by adding this line on dropzone init: function to assign the id to that hidden input:

this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("id", "fileMedia");

And now other things are easy because I removed multiple attribute by using this id on option change. Thank you very much for your kind assistance.

Comment: Glad I could aim you in the right direction at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to solve your problem,

you need to define a variable in javascript.

```
var myDropZone;
```

Initialize `myDropZone` vairable in `init()` event.

```
init: function() {

    myDropzone = this;
}
```

myDropzone became accessible so the statement

```
myDropzone.options.maxFiles = 1;
```

set `clickable:false` after a file upload done,

```
myDropzone.options.clickable = false;
```

remove file mannually after exceed max file limit.

```
myDropzone.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
    myDropzone.removeFile(file);
});
```

Comment: Thankx Mayank, I just tried and found it works in the way that still allowed multiple files but upload only first file. It's better than nothing but is it possible that dropzone only allow single file? when I manually set maxFiles=1 then it only allows single file but it is not working dynamically and user still can select multiple file.

Comment: Just checked but uploadMultiple is not working dynamically even manually. I wondered that multiple attribue is only removing by setting maxFiles=1 manually.

Comment: I have checked and found that it is working but as a workaround. Because user still can select multiple images. Selecting multiple images may be confusing for end user. But many thanks for your kind assistance because I learnt many new things by your answer. Currently I get my requirements by implementing Ryan's answer.

Comment: if your problem not yet solve, you can make clickable:false after a single upload done.

Comment: Thank you very much but the problem is resolved by adding id to hidden input and then accessing this id and removing multiple attribute.

Comment: happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks, "Initialize myDropZone vairable in init() event" saved me