# jQuery append with variable as src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just learning jQuery and cannot get my variable into `src` when I use `append`. It either doesn't work at all, or I just get the string representation of my variable name when I look in the console.

This is my offending code:

```
var $googleURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location="+$googleStreet+","+$googleCity;

$($body).append('<img src='$googleURL'></img>');
```

I don't want to use `attr` because there is no `img` tag on the page, just a `body` tag. Where did I go astray?

Comment: You use `+` to concat variables in jQuery. Also, there is no need using `$` as a variable-precursor in jQuery. Could be worth reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try

```
  $($body).append("<img src='"+ $googleURL + "'></img>");
```

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript, you can put variables inside strings using `+`

Like this: `"string, " + variable + ", more string"`

Try this code, it may work depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

```
var googleURL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location='+googleStreet+','+googleCity;
```

`$($body).append('<img src="' + googleURL + '"></img>');`