# Can we have jQuery object inside another jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have an issue, but have had times when I got code that didn't work because there was a jQuery object inside another jQuery object.

So I'm just looking for some clarity on the matter. I've looked for answers on this but haven't found anything.

Can we have:

```
var element1 = $("some-element");
$(element1).addClass("hidden");
```

Not sure if I'm just stupid (by no means a JavaScript or jQuery expert. I'm still quite junior), but I just wanted to find out what the deal with this is.

Comment: [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#cloning-jquery-objects): _"When a jQuery object is passed to the $() function, a clone of the object is created. This new jQuery object references the same DOM elements as the initial one."_

Comment: Can you please create fiddle and explain in detail?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. A fiddle to explain a bit more. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkzp32r8/15/)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use like this you can just use this way

```
var element1 = $("some-element");
element1.addClass("hidden");
```

you can you jquery object inside jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

I can for example this, hope to have the same idea with your problem

```
function buildArray(variable){
    if (variable.constructor === Array) return variable;
    return toArray(variable);
}
```

So, when i call `buildArray` function and pass `variable` parameter, it was `Array`. I can call member function of `Array` from `buildArray`.

Example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var index = buildArray(arr).indexOf(4);
```

With your question, can jQuery check with `$()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I am still confused by the question, even with the fiddle..

Correct me if I am wrong, but assigning the *name* `$element1` to a variable would behave no differently than using the name `element1`. It is simply used as a naming convention ([Hungarian Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553734/6224482)) in order to:

> distinguish jQuery objects which are stored in variables from
>   other variables

But using `$("#element1")` is effectively [*selecting*](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) HTML element(s) for manipulation.

I have [modified your Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hkzp32r8/16/), this would be my approach *personally* (although to be honest, this question is almost a little too broad and open to interpretation).

Comment: All I really wanted to find out is why my example doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
It does not explain my question.

I want to know why putting a jQuery object inside another jQuery object does not work. `$variable-name` vs `variable-name` has nothing to do with my question. If you take a closer look at the fiddle I linked in an earlier comment it should make more sense.