# PHP: Delete a row from a DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I have a table that pulls data from a DB and I'm trying to add a Remove/Delete button but it's not working and I can't really work out why.

JS Code

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeIteam', function (event) {
    var $iteamID = $(this).find('span').text();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "removeIteam.php",
        data: { BoxID: $iteamID }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });      
});
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    require_once('connent.php');
    function abc($BoxID){
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM client_info WHERE BoxID=$BoxID';
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Move over to MySQLi or PDO instead and use prepared statements. You are incredibly vulnerable.

Comment: You're not calling your PHP function anywhere.

Comment: your function is not executed.. remove the function and just place sql query.. `mysql_*` is deprecated and is remove in PHP7 use `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the PHP function. Furthermore I edited your code to be more secure and less vulnerable to SQL injections. However an even better option is to use [MysqlI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), like comments have already pointed out. I didn't want to make these modifications since I do not know the value of `$conn`.

JS Code

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeIteam', function (event) {
    var $iteamID = $(this).find('span').text();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "removeIteam.php",
        data: { BoxID: $iteamID }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });      
});
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    require_once('connent.php');
    $box_id = isset($_POST['BoxID']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BoxID']) : null;
    if($box_id == null) die("Missing BoxID.");

    $sql = "DELETE FROM client_info WHERE BoxID='".$box_id."'");
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
 ?>
```

Comment: I have tried with your edit's and I'm still getting an error `500 (Internal Server Error)` Any idea why?

Comment: @RyanJ try putting `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` somewhere on top of your page and check the error logs. If you are using PHP7 then you cannot use `mysql_` functions since they were removed.

Comment: @RyanJ have you checked the your PHP error logs? The location of the log file is different depending on how you installed php. For example, if you are using XAMPP or WAMP on Windows, the default location is `C:\Windows\Temp`

Comment: @thepieterdc When I added the code to show the errors nothing is happening other then the `500 (Internal Server Error)` showing in the console and it's the same when I use `mysqli_`

Answer (score -2):

make sure you stored the posted value in $boxID
And
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM client_info WHERE BoxID=$BoxID';
        $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

Comment: Your sentence explaining what to do seems alright but the code you posted doesn't do what you suggested.

Comment: btw, i just wanna say that dont use deprecated syntax. thats all

Comment: How do I do that? And is that not what `data: { BoxID: $iteamID }` is doing ?

Comment: remove $ sign. its a php syntax. var {variable name} is enough in jscript

Comment: @joseph also, don't just use the `mysqli_` function without explaining that you are doing that. (Even if it is a good call)

Comment: There is no need to remove the `$` from the Javascript variable name.

Answer (score -3):

Please remove the `$` (dollar sign) before the `var iteamID`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeIteam', function (event) {
    var iteamID = $(this).find('span').text(); //instead of var $iteamID = $(this).find('span').text();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "removeIteam.php",
        data: { BoxID: iteamID } //instead of data: { BoxID: $iteamID }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });      
});
```

Comment: Why? The `$` is perfectly valid.

Comment: It is not. Please try it in your code editor. This is javascript (jquery) not php

Comment: [Prepare to learn something new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: See how its used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign