# jQuery attribute selectors - why the quote marks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

In jQuery, when selecting by attribute value, why do we need to enclose the value in quotes `'` `'`?

```
  $("#demo-dropdown a").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(typeof (href));  // there shows `string`
    $("#tab-list li a[href= '" + href + "']" ).tab("show");  // why the single-quotes?

  });
```

If I use:

```
$("#tab-list li a[href=" + href + "]" ).tab("show");
```

then I will get a `Syntax Error`:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #tab-list li a[href= #profile]
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.html?_ijt=o70cto8b6ocd3tq2oh8bck1k4e:171)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how a jquery [attribute-equals-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) look like `[name=”value”]`.Note the quotes. In the below expression it is selecting an anchor tag element which have the matched `href`

```
$("#tab-list li a[href= '" + href + "']" ).tab("show"); 
                        ^            ^
  //attribute selector starts        //attribute selector ends
```

Answer (score 1):

You're [selecting based on attribute value](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). Much of the jQuery selector syntax is derived from CSS selector syntax, so some of the rules come from CSS.  If the value you're looking for (contained in the variable `href`) is not a valid [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), you need to enclose that sought-value in quotes, as you do with the single-quotes in your first code example. **You can't leave out the quotes when the value contains spaces.** (Your error message implies `href` starts with a space.) For even more robustness, escape the value too:

Poor:  `$("#tab-list li a[href=" + href + "]" )`

Okay:  `$("#tab-list li a[href='" + href + "']" )`

Better:  `$("#tab-list li a[href='" + $.escapeSelector(href) + "']" )`

Escaping is required if the value you're seeking could have quote marks in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you use a string variable in some place it doesn't also render the `"` or `'` around the string.

For example, when you simply do this

```
var someString = "Hello World";
console.log( someString );
```

You will see that it doesn't produce the quotes around the string even though the variable contains a string. Why? Because how inconvenient it would be to have to remove the `""` every time you want to use a string variable somewhere.

In reality you don't have the quotes around the string variable.

When you fetch the `href` attribute, say it looks something like `href='www.example.com'`, only the value is fetched, not the quotes around it. This is important as well, you don't want this to happen:

```
var someString = "Hello World"; 
$("#someElm").text( someString );
// Produces a result
// where the html looks like this 
// `<div id="someElm">"Hello World"</div>`
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

You shoud write as code below:

```
$("#tab-list").find('li').find("a[href='" + $href + "']");
```

The reason you must use "href='" + $href + "'" beacause href is attribute of tag a, $href is variable you want filter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't think that helps, breaking down the selector into jQuery functions. And I think your filter call is broken because it's missing square brackets in the selector. Before you post an answer it may be a good idea to test it, such as on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Thanks, I test it run ok

Comment: Great, but renaming `href` to `$href` should make no difference. JavaScript allows either one as a variable name. (Perhaps you're thinking along the lines of Perl or PHP?)

Comment: Thanks. 
I know that, but at here, I want set for user understand $href is variable, difference with attribute href, so need " ' " + $href + " ' "

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's needed. And it mildly contradicts [the convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553734/673991) to use dollar-sign-prefixed variable names for jQuery objects.

Comment: Again. Thank so much :)