# How to dynamically change the price via incrementing the input number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create my personal project, and I called this system as ordering system I used laravel for this and the front end javascript and jquery.

I have question

**Question:**

1. I used the append function of jquery to transfer value to other side. so i append **input type number** which the value automatically equal to **1**

The question if I increment the value of input type number how the price double if i increase the value of number?

Example of my output

[image: My output]

My Front end Codes:

```
        var tbody = $('#myTable').children('tbody');

        //Then if no tbody just select your table 
        var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#myTable');



        //my logic to increment quantity but not working.


        $("#qty_change").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
            alert("changed");            
        });


        //function for getting the data from search product by clicking to the table row

        $("tr#productClicked").click(function () {

            //to get the price in tr
            var price = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_price").text();

            //to get the menu in tr
            var menu_name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_name").text();

            //row count
            var rowCount = $('table#myTable tr:last').index() + 1;

            //append input to quantity the value is 1
            var input = '<input type="number" name="qty_number" class="form-control" value="1" id="qty_change" />';



            //Item must be editable
            var contenteditable = 'contenteditable=true';



            table.append('<tr><td>'+rowCount+'</td><td class="total">'+input+'</td><td '+contenteditable+'>'+menu_name+'</td><td>'+price+'</td><td>'+price+'</td></tr>');


        });
```

**Html Table:**

```
 <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr style="font-size: 14px; ">
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Qty</th>
    <th scope="col">Item</th>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align: right">Cost</th>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align: right">Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="font-size:14px;">                 
<tr>
    {{-- <td>1</td>
    <td>x 2</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>Feast Chicken</td>
    <td align="right">$10.00</td>
    <td align="right">$20.00</td> --}}
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

**New update:**

```
$('.amount > input[type="number"]').on('input', updateTotal);

        function updateTotal(e){
          var value = e.target.value;

          // Don't do anything if value is not valid
          // else you will see NaN in result.
          if (!value || value < 0)
            return;

          var $parentRow = $(e.target).parent().parent();
          var $siblingTotal = $parentRow.find('.total');
          var $siblingCost = $parentRow.find('.cost');

          var cost = $siblingCost.text();

          // parseInt and parseFloat because
          // `value` and `cost` are strings.
          value = parseInt(value);
          cost = parseFloat(cost);

          $siblingTotal.text(value * cost);
        }




$("tr#productClicked").click(function () {

            swal({
              title: "Are you sure?",
              text: "Once you will add it will automatically send to the cart",
              icon: "warning",
              buttons: true,
              dangerMode: true,
            })
            .then((willDelete) => {
              if (willDelete) {

                    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                      icon: "success",
                    });

                    swal("Menu Added", "You clicked the button!", "success");

                    //to get the price in tr
                    var price = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_price").text();

                    //to get the menu in tr
                    var menu_name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_name").text();

                    //row count
                    var rowCount = $('table#myTable tr:last').index() + 1;

                    //append input to quantity the value is 1
                    var input = '<input type="number" value="1">';



                    //Item must be editable
                    var contenteditable = 'contenteditable=true';



                    table.append('<tr><td>'+rowCount+'</td><td class="amount">'+input+'</td><td '+contenteditable+'>'+menu_name+'</td><td class="cost">'+price+'</td><td class="total">'+price+'</td></tr>');


              } else {
                swal("Cancelled");
              }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Listen for ["input" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) using jQuery's [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

(Please note that "input" event has nothing to do with jQuery, it's a native JavaScript thing.)

This is a sample code, because the code you provided is not complete. But you should be able to get the concept:

---

**Usual code sample**

```js
$('.amount > input[type="number"]').on('input', updateTotal);

function updateTotal(e){
  var amount = parseInt(e.target.value);
  
  if (!amount || amount < 0)
    return;
    
  var $parentRow = $(e.target).parent().parent();
  var cost = parseFloat($parentRow.find('.cost').text());
  var total = (cost * amount).toFixed(2);
  
  $parentRow.find('.total').text(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Cost per item</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="amount"><input type="number" value="1"></td>
      <td class="cost">27</td>
      <td class="total">27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="amount"><input type="number" value="1"></td>
      <td class="cost">14.50</td>
      <td class="total">14.50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**For the sake of understanding**

```js
// Get all inputs with type="number"
// that is a child of <td class="amount">.
var $amountInput = $('td.amount > input[type="number"]');

// Attach "input" event listener to the input fields
// so that we know when the value changes and handle the changes.
// In this case, the event handler is the function "updateTotal".
$amountInput.on('input', updateTotal);


function updateTotal(e){
  // Get the `input` element that triggers this event.
  var $thisInput = $(e.target);

  // Get the value of $thisInput
  var amount = $thisInput.val();
  
  // The `value` is a string,
  // so we need `parseInt` to make it a number.
  // Use `parseInt` because quantity can't have decimals.
  amount = parseInt(amount);

  // Don't do anything if value is not valid
  // else you will see NaN in result.
  if (!amount || amount < 0)
    return;

  // Get the parent <tr> of this input field
  var $parentRow = $thisInput.parent().parent();
  
  // Find the <td class="total"> element
  var $siblingTotal = $parentRow.find('.total');
  
  // Find the <td class="cost"> element
  var $siblingCost = $parentRow.find('.cost');

  // Get the cost from <td class="cost"> element
  var cost = $siblingCost.text();

  // The "cost" is a string,
  // so we need `parseFloat` to make it a number.
  // Use `parseFloat` because cost can have decimals.
  cost = parseFloat(cost);

  // Calculate the total cost
  var total = amount * cost;
  
  // .toFixed(2) to force 2 decimal places
  total = total.toFixed(2);
  
  // Update the total cost into <td class="total"> element
  $siblingTotal.text(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Cost per item</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="amount"><input type="number" value="1"></td>
      <td class="cost">27</td>
      <td class="total">27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="amount"><input type="number" value="1"></td>
      <td class="cost">14.50</td>
      <td class="total">14.50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Note**

If you still have difficulties understanding, you might want to read:

1. [Why prefix "$" sign in only some variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign) (Generally called the [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation))
2. What is [`td.amount > input[type="number"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)?
3. What is [jQuery's `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?
4. What is [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)?
5. What is [jQuery's `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)?
6. What is [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)?
7. What is [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)?
8. [What does `!value` mean?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)
9. Why do you [`return` nothing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)?
10. What is [jQuery's `.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)?
11. What is [jQuery's `.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)?
12. What is [jQuery's `.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)?
13. What is [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)?

Comment: I give up for this, however it won't work to my codes. there is no error found , I already change the class i will give update

Comment: @DevGe saw your update, mate. You can't just copy paste it because it's only a **sample** code. You need to also make changes to your HTML to include the classes and change the codes to fit your HTML. I will update my code to be more descriptive.

Comment: hi, thank you for the effort thank you I already understand .. thank you bro again.

Comment: hi @Yong Quan, how to insert string currency like dollar?

Comment: @DevGe lol keyboard key. Like how you inserted that symbol from your original code I guess?

Comment: What i mean for this is if i tried to put $ or the string of currency the value turn to NAN