# Loading style button doesn't reset when called in quick succession

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [Inline Button Loader For Bootstrap 4 - Bootstrap4C Spinners](https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/inline-button-loader-bootstrap.html) to show loading action when clicked.
I am also calling the click action manually in my javascript for every word that gets entered. Problem is when I type the word one by one and waiting for the response (which takes a second), the button transition works correctly. However if i type multiple words back to back without waiting for the response then the button always gets stuck in loading state.

You can observe the behavior here: http://34.66.22.154:8000/

Here is my index.html:

```
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='../static/style.css'>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/cmGauge.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/cmGauge.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../static/component-spinners.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class='center'>
                <div class='title'>Sentiment Analysis of Movie Reviews</div>
                <div class='content'>
                    <form action="/analyze" id="analyzeForm" class="form" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">                            
                            <textarea id = "review_id" rows = "10" cols = "100" name = "review_name" class="review_class"></textarea><br>
                        </div> 
                        <div class='analyze'>                            
                            <button id="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-spinner btn-spinner-example" value="Analyze" data-spinner-text="Analyzing...">Analyze</button>
                        </div>                        
                    </form> 
                    <b>Negative</b>
                    <div id="gaugeDemo" class="gauge gauge-big gauge-green">                        
                        <div class="gauge-arrow" data-percentage="40"
                            style="transform: rotate(0deg);"></div>
                    </div>
                    <b>Positive</b>
                    <div class='result'>
                        <br><p id="result"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="result2"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var globalWordCount = 0
                        var indicator = 50
                        var btn
                        var gauge = $('#gaugeDemo .gauge-arrow')
                        gauge.cmGauge();
                        gauge.trigger('updateGauge', indicator);
                        $('.btn-spinner-example').click(function() {
                            console.log("Button click start");
                            btn = $(this);
                            $(btn).buttonLoader('start');
                        });                         
                        function word_count(field, count) {
                            var number = 0;
                            var matches = $(field).val().match(/\s/g);                            
                            if(matches) {
                                number = matches.length;
                            }                           

                            if (globalWordCount != number) {                                
                                globalWordCount = number                               
                                $("#submit_button").click();
                            }
                        }
                        // Enable button if some text entered
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('.btn').attr('disabled',true);                            
                            $('#review_id').keyup(function(){
                                if($(this).val().length !=0){
                                    $('.btn').attr('disabled', false);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $('.btn').attr('disabled', true);        
                                }
                            })                            
                        });

                        $('.review_class').each(function() {
                            var input = '#' + this.id;
                            var count = input + '_count';
                            $(count).show();
                            word_count(input, count);
                            $(this).keyup(function() { word_count(input, count) });
                        });

                        // Attach a submit handler to the form
                        $( "#analyzeForm" ).submit(function( event ) {                         
                          // Stop form from submitting normally
                          event.preventDefault();                          
                          // Get some values from elements on the page:
                          var $form = $( this ),
                            //term = $form.find( "input[name='review_name']" ).val(),
                            text = $form.find( "textarea" ).val(),
                            url = $form.attr( "action" );
                            //console.log(text, "text");

                          // Send the data using post
                          var posting = $.post( url, { review_name: text } );

                          // Put the results in a div
                          posting.done(function( data ) {
                            var indicator = ('Negative' === data.prediction) ? 100 - data.confidence : data.confidence;            
                            gauge.trigger('updateGauge', indicator);                                                        
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data.prediction + " with confidence of " + data.confidence + "%";
                            $(btn).buttonLoader('stop');
                            console.log("Button click stop");
                          });                          
                        });
                    </script>                                                             
                </div>
                <div class='footer'>
                    <p><br><br><br><br><br><br><a href="https://github.com/nikhilno1/nlp_projects">Code on GitHub</a>
                    <br><i>Powered by Hugging Face's awesome pytorch-transformers library</i></p>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/component-spinners.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you please let me know how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the spinner component.

When `buttonLoader('start')` is called, it saves the original button text in an attribute:

```
$(self).attr('data-btn-text', $(self).text());
```

But if the button is already spinning and its text is already set to `data-spinner-text`, then both `data-spinner-text` and `data-btn-text` are set to the same value and the original button text is lost.

It seems that this is supposed to be prevented by returning `false` if the button is already disabled:

```
if ($(self).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
  return false;
}
```

But the component doesn't set the disabled attribute when it's started:

```
$(self).addClass('disabled');
```

---

One quick solution is to stop the button before starting it.
This should prevent multiple overlapping calls to start the button.

```
$('.btn-spinner-example').click(function() {
  console.log("Button click start");
  $btn = $(this);
  $btn.buttonLoader('stop');
  $btn.buttonLoader('start');
});
```

Note that it's not necessary to make a jQuery object of a variable that's already a jQuery object:

```
btn = $(this);
$(btn).buttonLoader('start');
```

In fact, I might define the submit button once and use that definition throughout:

```
let $submitBtn = $('#submit_button');

$submitBtn.on('click',(function() {
  console.log("Button click start");
  $submitBtn.buttonLoader('stop');
  $submitBtn.buttonLoader('start');
});
```

Also, it seems that you're including the jQuery library twice in your document.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried adding stop before start but with this I don't even see the button changing to loading. It always remains the same. I am not a UI guy, I just wanna put together something to demonstrate my ML app. So once something works, I am hesitant to change it. :)

Comment: Hey, i used $(btn) instead of $btn and it worked. :) What is the difference between $btn and $(btn)?

Comment: [`$()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) "searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements". But since you've already defined `btn` as `$(this)`, it's already a jQuery object. I often define such a variable [with a dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553734/924299) like `$btn` to help me remember it's a jQuery object.